# Using an input from the user to assign to a variable in a second class

Tags: java

I am making a program with two classes, one to create methods and the other as the tester class. I am having difficulties assigning the input to a new variable, which needs to be used to invoke the methods from the other class.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    int obj = new NumberUtility(0);
    System.out.println("Enter a number. Enter 0 to end");
    obj = scan.nextInt();
```

As example here is the beginning of the other class

```
public class NumberUtility {
int n = 0;
public NumberUtility(int n) {
    getN();
    isEven();
    isOdd();
}
public int getN() {
    return n;
}
public boolean isEven() {
    if((n % 2 == 0)) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

My code is incomplete elsewhere but that is the main issue I have been trying to work around. Since if I set it to an int, it won't work. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to java coding.

Comment: You're trying to access the user input from class NumberUtility?

Comment: If you are trying to assign input to `obj`, then first try to define obj as `NumberUtility obj = new NumberUtility(0);`. Next, try to add a setter method in the class so that you can assign input to `n` as `obj.setN(scan.nextInt());`. Assigning `NumberUtility` to `int` type seems weird here.

Comment: No, I'm trying to have the user input from the tester class. Then I want to use that variable to invoke the methods from NumberUtility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line:

```
int obj = new NumberUtility(0);
```

you are attempting to assign a new NumberUtility object to the variable `obj` which is of type int.  You cannot do that! That's like trying to create a doghouse, and then shoving your dog into a birdhouse. They're just not compatible.

As well, later, you try to reassign obj to the result of scan, which would work, but probably not what you want, as `obj` is still an int:

```
obj = scan.nextInt();
```

I think what you want to do is something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number. Enter 0 to end");

    // Read a number from the scanner
    int number = scan.nextInt();

    // Create a new NumberUtility from this primitive integer
    NumberUtility obj = new NumberUtility(number);

    System.out.println("Even? " + obj.isEven());
```

By the way, you can simplify your isEven method as well:

```
public boolean isEven() {
    return (n % 2 == 0);
}
```

Edit: I see I'm not done yet.

In the NumberUtility class, you have defined a constructor for the class:

```
public NumberUtility(int n) {
    getN();
    isEven();
    isOdd();
}
```

This seems like an odd thing to do.  You are ignoring the input (int n) and then calling all the methods of the class which don't really do much.

I think you want your constructor to be something like this:

```
public NumberUtility(int input_n) {
    // Save the constructor's input parameter to the member field 'n'
    this.n = input_n;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add a correct constructor to the example code, without that n will always be 0 with the code from the question

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.

Comment: No problem. @SusLord1 if you feel this answers your question, please click the checkmark to mark it as "Answered".